# Mixture density Network, MDN

Tags: python, machine-learning

In the Mixture density Network, there is a function to sample the multiple predictions which is :

```
y_test = model.predict(x_test)
y_samples = np.apply_along_axis(mdn.sample_from_output, 1, y_test, OUTPUT_DIMS, N_MIXES, temp=1.0)
```

So, here this function only return one sample while I should get number of samples= N_MIXES. Any thought on how to get the multiple samples?

Answer (score 0):

In line 251 of init.py, change it like this:

```py
sample = np.random.multivariate_normal(mus_vector, cov_matrix, n_samp)
```

Pass `n_samp` as a parameter in line 224 as:

```py
def sample_from_output(params, output_dim, num_mixes, n_samp=100, temp=1.0, sigma_temp=1.0):
```